# Ratio of items in an array always returns zero ~ HackerRank Plus Minus Problem

Tags: java

This code below works out the number of zeros, positive, and negative numbers in an array, then works out the ratio of positive, negative and zero items in the array.

```
public class Solution {

    static void plusMinus(int[] arr) {
        int pos = 0, neg = 0, zero = 0;
        int arrlength = arr.length;

        for(int i = 0; i < arrlength; i++){

           if(arr[i] > 1){
               pos += 1;
           } else if(arr[i] < 0){
               neg += 1;
           } else if(arr[i] == 0){
               zero += 1;
           }
         }

    double posfrac = pos/arr.length, negfrac = neg/arr.length, zerofrac = 
    zero/arr.length;

    System.out.println(posfrac);
    System.out.println(negfrac);
    System.out.println(zerofrac);
    }
```

My main function below is supposed to generate random arrays for plusMinus(), so that I can test plusMinus() with a variety of cases.

```
    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        int[] arr = new int[n];

        String[] arrItems = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int arrItem = Integer.parseInt(arrItems[i]);
            arr[i] = arrItem;
        }

        plusMinus(arr);

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

My code doesn't return anything when I run it.  I get the output:

```
0.0
0.0
0.0
```

Comment: You are performing integer math. `double posfrac = pos/arr.length` should be `double posfrac = pos/(double)arr.length` - if both terms are `int` you perform integer division, and then promote to a `double`.

Comment: One issue I see in the code which is not related to the question is that in the Positive number checking you should use the condition of ```arr[i]>=1``` or it will miss checking for 1. And answering your question it could be a case of Integer division that is why it gets rounded off to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. 
First the condition of checking for positive either make it as `arr[i]>=1` or `arr[i]>0`

public class Solution {

```
static void plusMinus(int[] arr) {
    float pos = 0, neg = 0, zero = 0;
    float arrlength = arr.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < arrlength; i++){

       if(arr[i] > 0){
           pos += 1;
       } else if(arr[i] < 0){
           neg += 1;
       } else if(arr[i] == 0){
           zero += 1;
       }
     }

double posfrac = pos/arrlength , negfrac = neg/arrlength , zerofrac = 
zero/arrlength ;

System.out.println(posfrac);
System.out.println(negfrac);
System.out.println(zerofrac);
}
```